Kestrel throws "400 Bad Request: Invalid Target" for URLs with non-ASCII characters when using NGINX as reverse proxy
I am currently migrating a project from IIS to NGINX, and I’m encountering an issue when handling URLs that contain non-ASCII characters. Previously, on IIS, URLs with non-ASCII characters worked fine. Now, with my new setup, NGINX is proxying requests to a Kestrel server. However, when I try to access URLs containing non-ASCII characters (e.g., Cyrillic or accented characters), Kestrel throws a 400 Bad Request: Invalid Target error.
Here's the key part of my NGINX configuration:
location / {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8092;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}

How can I modify the URL (particularly encoding the non-ASCII characters) before passing it to Kestrel in a way that Kestrel can process it without throwing the 400 Bad Request: Invalid Target error? I would prefer to handle this in NGINX without altering proxy_pass or other things that is better than this
I cannot modify the calling URLs.
Kestrel processes the request before any middleware runs, so I cannot fix the URL at the application level.
Kestrel throws a 400 Bad Request: Invalid Target error when the URL contains non-ASCII characters.
I also tried access_by_lua_block but it didnt worked and uri that is going to my application was not changing.
location / {
    access_by_lua_block {
        -- Function to escape only the query string
        local function escape_query_string(uri)
            -- Split the URI into path and query string
            local path, query = uri:match("([^?]*)%?(.*)")
            if not query then
                ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "No query string found in URI.")
                return uri -- No query string to escape
            end

            -- Escape the query string
            local escaped_query = ngx.escape_uri(query)

            -- Recombine the path and escaped query string
            return path .. "?" .. escaped_query
        end

        -- Get the original URI
        local original_uri = ngx.var.request_uri
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "Original URI: ", original_uri)

        -- Escape only the query string
        local escaped_uri = escape_query_string(original_uri)
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "Escaped URI: ", escaped_uri)

        -- Set the URI to the escaped version
        ngx.req.set_uri(escaped_uri)
        ngx.log(ngx.ERR, "URI set to: ", ngx.var.request_uri)
    }

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8092;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
}


You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 400 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.
